# How to delete directory with symlinks, without deleting their targets?

Tags: ant, symlink, delete-file

I am running an Ant command like:

```
<delete dir="/some/folder/path/"/>
```

The folder `/path/` contains some files, folders and some symlinks. The files and folders are deleted but the command tries to delete the `target` directories of the symlinks which gives an error.

I don't want to delete the target directories but only the symlinks when I run the `<delete>` command on the parent folder (`/path/`).

Comment: Ant is 'a tool commonly used by programmers'. It doesn't make sense to me that this is closed. I also have a better answer to provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this bugreport](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22632).

A solution is to use fileset.

```
<delete>
  <fileset dir="/some/folder/path/" followsymlinks="false"/>
</delete>
```

Edit: the above does not delete symlinks, though. The following deletes all symlinks in a folder. I found it [here](http://ant.1045680.n5.nabble.com/Making-the-delete-task-behave-like-bin-rm-rf-vis-a-vis-symlinks-to-directories-td1355232.html).

```
<exec output="/path/to/symlink/list" executable="/usr/bin/find">
    <arg value="/some/folder/path/"/>
    <arg value="-type"/>
    <arg value="l"/>
</exec>

<fileset id="victims" dir="/some/folder/path/">
    <includesfile name="/path/to/symlink/list>
</fileset>
```

After this it should be safe to use delete dir.

Comment: It didnt worked  for  me  with Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
<delete failonerror="true" includeemptydirs="true" verbose="true" ><fileset refid="victims" /></delete>
I dint  get any error  but  dead  links  are  still  present.
Please  take  my 50  cents: if  we  are allowed  to  execute  "/usr/bin/find -l" ,  what  prohibits  us  using "/bin/rm -rf" ?

Comment: @aprodan That's a good point regarding `/usr/bin/find`. I'm not sure what I was thinking at the time. I haven't used ant in many years, so best of luck finding a solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

use "rm -rf" from bash.
I can't find a better solution

```
<macrodef name="bash_rm">
    <attribute name="dir" />
    <sequential>
        <echo message="Remove directory @{dir}"/>
        <exec executable="rm" >
            <arg value="-rf"/>
            <arg value="@{dir}" />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```